# error: eof expected but '}' found. } in playframework 2.3.9

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I am using play framwork 2.3.9. and my build.sbt is giving error **error: eof expected but '}' found.
}
^**

Below is my **build.sbt** file

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "ReliaCloud"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
//added this for 2.3
  lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore, jdbc, javaJdbc,
    "org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia" % "1.0.1",
    "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.10.1",
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
    "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4"
  )
  val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava).settings(
resolvers += "Maven repository" at "http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/",
resolvers += "MongoDb Java Driver Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/",
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
  )
}
```

Not able to figure out why I am getting this error.
My application is build using playframework 2.2 and I am trying to migrate it to playframework 2.3.xx

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the document [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23#Auto-Plugins-and-plugin-settings), in regards to plugin settings, when you move from 2.2 to 2.3 in Playframework's Java version.

**Little note**: If it possible move to the latest versions currently 2.6; and soon to be 2.7. They are much more efficient and secure.

Comment: my final aim is to migrate from 2.2 to 2.6 only, but if i directly start from 2.2 to 2.6 it be very difficult is what i thought

Comment: @abhi the main shift for me was injection and filtering concepts. I would suggest to start with a latest clean starter app, and move a tests and then route -> controller -> model/service -> controller -> view at a time. This is because you will put a lot of time migrating and you will be still behind the latest version.

Comment: So you are suggesting to directly migrate to 2.6?

Comment: @abhi yes I do. What is the point on upgrading from a older version to another old version? As I said do it one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I think what you suggest makes sense

Comment: @sayed can we use socialsecure with play 2.6 ? If not what would be the good alternative for socialsecure